# Python 3.9 module not found after installing with pip

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, pip, jupyter-notebook

I have tried the following install commands -

```
python3.9 -m pip install plotly

pip3 install plotly
```

But jupyter notebook in vs code gives the following error

```
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-7-f6b2d252d652> in <module>
      1 import pandas as pd
      2 import numpy as np
----> 3 import plotly

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'plotly'
```

However, when I do the same code in a jupyter notebook through anaconda, it works. I would like to be able to use pip modules in vs code too as it is my favourite editor. I have tried changing the python version used in the jupyter notebook but it did not work.

Ps. I am using a mac

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's probably because VSCode is using the wrong version of Python.

Take a look at the bottom right corner. While I have Python 3.8 and 3.9 installed, VSC is using 3.7.6 version. You have to click there and select the correct version.

[image]

Comment: the jupyter notebook uses 3.9 and vs code is showing 3.8. I fixed it. It worked. thanks a ton

Comment: However now vs code is giving autocomplete while importing the desired module, but then says that the module is not defined

Comment: Moreover, I am using python 3.9. and in vs code it is giving to paths to it - 
1. library/frameworks/python and so on
2. usr/local/bin/python3